# Schengen Visa application in status "RESOLVED"

Tags: visas, schengen, terminology, application-status

My Schengen visa application  status shows ("RESOLVED"). What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please review: http://www.indiana.edu/~icy/netiquette.html.  Especially Rule ii.

Comment: Could you perhaps include a screenshot or more detail?

Comment: what country's embassy, u applied in ?

Comment: @Karlson the link has rotted.

Comment: A legitimate reason for "RESOLVED" in a question title!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I suspect it would have in over 2 years.

Answer (score 5):

Surely this just means that your visa is RESOLVED? ;-)

Without a screenshot, it's hard to be sure, but my best guess is that any problems with the visa have now been solved, and it will be issued in due course.

Comment: A guess it not really enough, right? Would be good if you could support this with facts, links or citations.